# Big Sur Mail all archives folder

Tags: mail.app, email, big-sur, mail-rules

In Big Sur the mail client doesn't show a folder combining archives of all accounts. I'd like to have such a folder and tried creating a smart mailbox for this purpose as I'd successfully done to create an All Junk folder.

Here's the smart mailbox configuration that I thought would work:
[image: smart mailbox rule]

However, it throws this error:
[image: smart mailbox error]

Any tips on how I can access an archive across accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Mailboxes column showing click the plus sign to the right of the header "Favourites", which appears when hovering the pointer over it.
[image: add to Favourites]

Then, in the resulting window, select "All Archive" as the Mailbox to add:
[image: All Archive]

Comment: Ah, great! My app didn't show a ´+´when hovering the favourites header at first, but it appeared when I ticked the 'hide favourites bar' setting for some reason...

Comment: Ah yes, the favourites bar covers it for some reason.  That should be fixed in the next update.